# Loop only running for the last iteration in R - Looping over participants

Tags: r

I am very new to R and I am trying to run a loop, so any help is greatly appreciated.

I have longitudinal data with multiple timepoints for each participant, which looks like the picture attached[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdFbf.png)

I need to replace the `NA` values with the values from when the `Years` variable is equal to 0, and I want to write a loop to do this for each participant. I have written some code which seems to work, however it only gives output for the last iteration of the loop (the last participant). This is the code I am using:

```
x <- c(1:4) 

n = length(x)

for(i in 1:n)
{
  data <- subset(df, ID %in% c(x[i]))
  
  data$outcome <- ifelse(is.na(data$outcome), 
                         data[1,3], 
                   data$outcome)
}
```

Using this code, the output gives only the last iteration (i.e. in this case, `ID` 4). I need to complete this for all IDs.

Any help is much appreciated! Thankyou.

Comment: I believe `ifelse` already does Row-wise computation. You might not need the loop at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% clear on your intent, but this will, within an ID, fill all `outcomes` missing values by the (first) `outcomes` value from a row where `Years == 0`.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(outcome = coalesce(outcome, first(outcomes[Years == 0])))
```

Obvioustly untested, but if you provide some sample data I'll happily help debug.

Comment: Alway appreciate a tidy solution, and it works when I test it. A little slow though? ```microbenchmark( base = my_dat$outcome <- ifelse(my_dat$year == 0 & is.na(my_dat$outcome), my_dat$years, my_dat$outcome), dplyr = my_dat %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(outcome = coalesce(outcome, first(outcome[years == 0]))) )```

Comment: @QAsena well, (a) we have different interpretations of the problem - you fill NA values only if they happen to occur on the row where `years == 0`. My reading of the problem is that OP wants to fill all missing values within an ID with the value from the row where `years == 0`. Maybe OP will clarify the problem...

Comment: (b) If you're not benchmarking on data large enough for the difference to be on the order of at least 0.01 seconds, it doesn't matter (unless this is time-sensitive production code...). If OP's intent does turn out to be a grouped operation, I'm pretty confident `dplyr` will be faster than `base` for any data big enough for the difference to be noticeable. Though of course I'd use `data.table` if I really cared about speed ;)

Comment: To be clear, your interpretation of the problem is shared by most of the other answers, but *"I need to replace the NA values with the values from when the Years variable is equal to 0, and I want to write a loop to do this for each participant."* makes me about 80% sure that my interpretation is correct.

Comment: Ah yes, you could be right about the interpretation. I should have said that I did blow up the problem size before doing the benchmarking. Op can pick the most relevant answer :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help everyone! Sorry the problem was not clearly stated or clarified - but Gregor your interpretation is correct, and your solution worked perfectly! Thank you very much.

Comment: @Gregor Thomas. I agree, with `data.table` for speed (I've seen `dplyr` beaten on the speed check by `base` but case by case on that one!). Currently I have a lot of speed and memory limitations with big datasets so my mind goes that way :D

Answer (score 0):

Your loop replaces `data$outcome` each iteration. That is why you only get the last result.

Here's my inelegant solution:

Making sample data to match yours (not including unused column)

```
my_dat <- data.frame("years" = sample(c(0, 1.5, 3), 30, replace = T),
                      "outcome" = as.numeric(sample(c("", 1, 2), 30, replace = T)))
```

Find which rows are both 0 for years and missing outcome

```
my_index <- my_dat$years == 0 * is.na(my_dat$outcome)
```

Assign 0 to replace NA:

```
my_dat$outcome[my_index] <- 0
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler tidyverse method:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  filter(ID %in% x) %>%
  mutate(outcome = ifelse(is.na(Outcome), Years, Outcome))
```

Answer (score 0):

your question could do with some clarification and a repreducible example. As I understand it from: "I need to replace the NA values with the values from when the Years variable is equal to 0". So if `outcome` equals `NA` and `Years` equals `0` you want `outcom` to equal `0`?

```
set.seed(1984) # ser the seed so that my_dat is the same each time
# using a modified df from markhogue answer...
my_dat <- data.frame(
  ID = 1:30,
  years = sample(c(0, 1.5, 3), 30, replace = T),
  outcome = as.numeric(sample(c("", 1, 2), 30, replace = T))
)
my_dat # have a look at rows 9 and 22
# ifelse given two conditions does year == 0 and is.na(outcome)
my_dat$outcome <- ifelse(my_dat$year == 0 & is.na(my_dat$outcome), my_dat$years, my_dat$outcome)
my_dat # have a look at rows 9 and 22
```

Let me know if this is what you need :)